# How do I get the left and right arrow keys to work with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I get the left and right arrow keys to work in this situation using jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#container').click(function()
    {
        var totalWidth = 0;
        var sizeWidth = $('#insertData1').outerWidth();
        $('#ul_a li').each(function()
            {
                var widthS = $(this).width();
                var textW = $(this).text();

                var widthN = parseInt(widthS,10);
                if((totalWidth + widthN) < sizeWidth)
                {
                    totalWidth = totalWidth + widthN;
                    $('#ul_b').append('<li>'  + textW + '</li>');
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });

        $('#ul_b li').hover(function() 
            {
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
            }, function() 
            {
                $(this).removeClass('highlight');
            });

        $('#ul_b li').keypress(function(e)
            {
                if(e.which == 37)
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
                    $(this).prev().addClass('highlight');
                }
                elseif(e.which == 39)
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
                    $(this).next().addClass('highlight');
                }
                return false;
            });
    });
});
```

By the way, even tried using `keyup` and get the same problem...

```
$('#ul_b li').keyup(function(e)         
    {                 
        if(e.keyCode == 37)             
        {                 
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');                 
            $(this).prev().addClass('highlight');             
        }
        elseif(e.keyCode == 39)             
        {                 
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');                 
            $(this).next().addClass('highlight');             
        }                 
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keydown` or `keyup`.  The `Keypress` event listener doesn't recognise non-character keys (the key code of the arrow keys at `keypress` are zero). Coincidentally, I've just written an arrow key script for another question.

See this Fiddle for an example of the key code script: http://jsfiddle.net/ATUEx/ ([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614340/listen-to-multiple-keydowns/7614586#7614586))

Note: I've found (and fixed) another error: `elseif` is not a valid JavaScript expression. Use `else if` (with a space in between `else` and `if`) instead.

---

Your fixed code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#container').click(function()
    {
        var totalWidth = 0;
        var sizeWidth = $('#insertData1').outerWidth();
        $('#ul_a li').each(function()
            {
                var widthS = $(this).width();
                var textW = $(this).text();
                var widthN = parseInt(widthS,10);
                if((totalWidth + widthN) < sizeWidth)
                {
                    totalWidth = totalWidth + widthN;
                    $('#ul_b').append('<li>'  + textW + '</li>');             
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;              
                }
            });

        $('#ul_b li').hover(function()
            {
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
            }, function() 
            {
                $(this).removeClass('highlight');
            });

        $('#ul_b li').keydown(function(e)
        {
            if(e.which == 37)
            {
                $(this).removeClass('highlight');
                $(this).prev().addClass('highlight');
            }
            else if(e.which == 39)
            {
                $(this).removeClass('highlight');
                $(this).next().addClass('highlight');
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you fully read my answer? I had detected another error: `elseif` should be `else if`.

Comment: thanks for the answer Rob, even changing the elseif to else if, this problem continues.

Comment: Could you describe your problem with more detail? What error messages do you get? Also show the relevant HTML code.

Comment: When I use the document as the target, I do get an alert("keycode 37") or an alert("keycode 38") but the problem is that next or pre li data does not get highlighted using the .highlight class. So bascially, I have horizontal list of data being displayed from ul li list. Once it is displayed, I want to highlight each item in the list using the left or right arrow keys.

Comment: The left or right arrow keys never move but the alert keycode 37 or 39 is generated.

Comment: Also, $(this).removeClass('highlight') is working but the $(this).prev().addClass('highlight') and $(this).next().addClass('highlight') are not working.