# How to bind simultaneous events with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, mouseevent, keyboard-events

How do I bind simultaneous events to selector in jQuery?

I don't mean how to catch EITHER click or hover on some element, but how to catch two events under condition that BOTH of them occur simultaneously. For example, mouseover and keydown, or click and keydown, like shift+click etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Catching mouseover+keydown is very different from shift+click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detecting shift + click is easy: Check the `shiftKey` property of the `event` object.

Checking a pressed key + mouse event (simultaneously), on the other hand...:

- Bind an event to the keydown/keyup function, which stores the `event.keyCode` or `event.which` in a variable
- Create a poller function, which periodically resets this variable, so that only key strokes within the last (example:) 300 milliseconds are counted
- Add a `mousedown` event, which checks the last remembered keyCode, if existent, and execute the relevant code, if applicable.

For a full code which handles multiple events (two keydown events, in the example), see **[my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614340/listen-to-multiple-keydowns/7614586#7614586)**.

Comment: Well that is closest to what I already tried, exept for periodically reseting the variable, that sounds like good idea. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple event types can be bound at once by including each one separated by a space:

```
$('#foo').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('entered');
});
```

Comment: He wants the function to fire only when the two events happen. This won't work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery bind

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch a mouse event and a keyboard event simultaneously or any event, that's because every event handler can handle only one event at a time.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery doesn't offer any such functionality out of the box. You have to track the state changes yourself through events.