# How do I get repeat keyboard events in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the keyup and keydown events to get user's keystrokes. These events do just that: fire when the key is up or down.

However, I'd like to get a repeat event when a key stays pressed.

What event should I be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **[`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)** event for this purpose. Example:

```
$('element').keypress(function(ev){
    var character = String.fromCharCode(ev.which); //Code to character conversion
})
```

The key events are fired in the following order:

- `keydown` - Once
- `keypress` - Multiple times
- `keyup` - Once (`preventDefault()` cannot prevent default behaviour any more, at this point)

Comment: You can use keydown in conjunction with setInterval; which might be better for whatever he's doing, since he would be able to set the interval time.

Comment: If that's the case, this answer might interest you: [Listen to multiple keydowns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614340/listen-to-multiple-keydowns/7614586#7614586)

Comment: Thanks, I was using keydown, keypress is better.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `keydown` event.  Not sure whether it is better to use one or the other.

### Note

You can use this in conjuction with setInterval to repeat an event.