# Why e.repeat is not working and have no errors in the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.repeat) { return }
    if (e.key == 'q' || e.key == 'Q') {
        $('.box.green').addClass('active').click();
    } else if (e.key == 'w' || e.key == 'W') {
        $('.box.red').addClass('active').click();
    } else if (e.key == 'a' || e.key == 'A') {
        $('.box.yellow').addClass('active').click();
    } else if (e.key == 's' || e.key == 'S') {
        $('.box.blue').addClass('active').click();
    } else { return }
    $(document).on('keyup', function() {
        $('.box').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

this code stores when any of the `'q', 'w', 'a', 's'` key is clicked in an array.
this works fine until I click and hold any key which results in repeated input.
for dealing with this I used `if (e.repeat) { return }` but this is not working and does not give any error in the console.
Help Me to find what I am doing wrong.

here is the remaining relevant code if it helps

```
var boxName = ['Q', 'W', 'A', 'S'];

$('.box').click(function() {
    userPattern.push(boxName.indexOf(this.textContent));
    console.log(boxName.indexOf(this.textContent));
});
```

Comment: `keydown` won't repeat, since it is fired only once. Use the `keypress` event to achieve what you want. Not exactly a duplicate question... But closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029274/how-do-i-get-repeat-keyboard-events-in-jquery

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette hey there, I changed my first two lines with your's but it still not working instead it is now registering two clicks on one click.  Help 

Comment: ok... Then try to only use the `keypress` event.

Comment: nope, still not working.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette keydown will repeat when the key is held. You need to use a `keyup` event which can't repeat

Comment: Yes... I noticed it too @ParkingMaster. But strangely, the jQuery event object doesn't have the `repeat` property at all. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `repeat` property isn't defined at all in the jQuery event (`e`) object.

```js
$(document).on("keydown keypress", function (e) {
   console.log(e.repeat);
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Press and old any key...
```

But using `addEventListener`, it works with `keydown`. You will notice that the very first log is `false` and all the other ones are `true`.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  console.log(e.repeat); // If pressed more then once (in less then 1000ms) "true"
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
Press and hold any key...
```

---

Here is a code suggestion for you:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.repeat) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(`The "${e.key}" is down.`);
  if (e.key == 'q' || e.key == 'Q') {
    $('.box.green').addClass('active').click();
  } else if (e.key == 'w' || e.key == 'W') {
    $('.box.red').addClass('active').click();
  } else if (e.key == 'a' || e.key == 'A') {
    $('.box.yellow').addClass('active').click();
  } else if (e.key == 's' || e.key == 'S') {
    $('.box.blue').addClass('active').click();
  } else {
    return;
  }
});

// It is a good practice NOT to have event handlers defined in another one.
$(document).on('keyup', function() {
  // clear the console
  console.clear()
  $('.box').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.active {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Press and hold any of the "q", "w", "a", "s" keys

<div class="box green">GREEN</div>
<div class="box red">RED</div>
<div class="box yellow">YELLOW</div>
<div class="box blue">BLUE</div>
```

And about the `keyup` handler: you may want to remove the active class only on the relevant element instead of all the `.box` elements...

---

Additionally: It is a good practice NOT to have event handlers defined in another one to avoid registering multiple times the same handler.

Comment: I was building a 2d parking game a couple months ago. I had a serious problem when you press and hold the key, the car speeds up (a lot) and freezes the page. Now that I already solved that problem, I found this (event.repeat). This would have been good if I still had that problem :)

Comment: hi there, thanks a lot and well explained. finally, it solves my problem but still, I have a question. why it doesn't give any errors? 

Comment: Under jQuery, the condition `if (e.repeat)` always resolve as `false` because `undefined` is "falsy". There is no error to throw here.

Comment: ok. your first code snippet explains it. thanks 

Answer (score 0):

...is working

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.repeat) {
    return false;
  };
};
```

[MDN KeyboardEvent #Auto-repeat handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#auto-repeat_handling)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.