# How to set a hotkey combination of 2 letters with jQuery hotkey.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hotkeys

I've use jQuery hotkey.js plugin in my application to support shortcut keys.
But, currently seems it only support key combinations like "ctrl+a","shift+a","alt+a"... I've tried

```
$(document).bind('keypress','g+g',fn);
```

or

```
$(document).bind('keypress','g,g',fn);
```

or even

```
$(document).bind('keypress','g','g',fn);
```

but non of them work.

My question would be what can I do to support this kind of hotkeys?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You will need CTRL, or Alt for making shortcut. And how are you suppose to do a shortcut with 2 g's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortcut.js only supports a modifier key (alt, ctrl, meta, shift) + another key. It does not support multiple non-modifier keys (e.g `r+g`, or even `ctrl+e+f` (**[proof case](http://jsfiddle.net/gqJEG/)**)).

Have a look at the linked answer for another method to achieve the desired effect.

**SO answer: [Listen to multiple keydowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614340/listen-to-multiple-keydowns/7614586#7614586)**