# Logging which keys have been pressed and in which order javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a html canvas game and need to log if there was a successful order of keys being pressed.

The keys that have to be pressed in this order are

**z** then **a**

If z and then a is pressed it should trigger an event. How can this be best done?!

Thanks

Comment: Plain JS or do you use e.g. jQuery?

Comment: Jquery , javascript or both, just about to edit my answer with what I have tried :)

Comment: Should both keys be pressed at the same time, or is it allowed to lifet the previous key before pressing the next one? A pure JavaScript solution is [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614340/listen-to-multiple-keydowns/7614586#7614586) (use the `keypress` event, together with the `event.charCode` property for a reliable key-to-char mapping).

Comment: The keys should be pressed alternatively, thanks for the link :)

Comment: DEMO included in my answer. Take a look!

Answer (score 0):

```
var keys = [];

$("div").keypress(function(e){
    keys[keys.length] = e.keyCode;
})
```

This will do it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/9LKby/

More specific to your "z and a" example:

```
var keys = [];                                         //store in an array (list)

$("body").keypress(function(e){                                //keypress event
    keys[keys.length] = e.keyCode;                             //save keyCodes
    if(keys[keys.length-2]==122 && keys[keys.length-1]==97){   //122 = Z; 97 = A
        alert("You have just pressed z and then a");           //done
    }
})​;
```

Comment: Why not use `.push()`? Besides that, better use `e.which` and I'd use a string instead of an array - then you can easily check `if(keys == 'za')` to see if the correct keys have been pressed.

Comment: How do you mean thiefMaster?!

Comment: @ThiefMaster - You can only fetch `keyCode`, not the actual character. `e.which` will give you the `keyCode` as well. No different.

Comment: @Derek: *"To determine which character was entered, examine the event object that is passed to the handler function. While browsers use differing properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the `.which` property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the character code."* - http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: Yes, I realize this. But `.keyCode` might not work in all browsers - *that's* why you should use `.which`. But yeah i see how my previous comment was confusing...

Comment: `keyCode` should be probably cross browser compatible.